# Webpack: module build failed

Tags: npm, webpack, webix

I am running `npm run dev` with this simple app.js:

```
//import {JetApp, EmptyRouter, HashRouter } from "webix-jet";
import {JetApp} from "webix-jet/dist/es6/jet";
```

I am getting this error - not sure what i'm missing.

> Module build failed: Module not found:
> "./assets/app.js" contains a reference to the file "webix-jet/dist/es6/jet".
> This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

I've added webix and webix-jet via npm and I can see their sources/dist under `node_modules`

Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you import it from dist? You should import from "webix-jet", like in the first commented line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, normally you code must look like

```js
import {JetApp} from "webix-jet";
```

so you need to import just from webix-jet module, there is no need to define exact file ( be sure that you have webix-jet as dependency in the package.json )

Also, this line `./assets/app.js"` looks strange as well, as app.js is expected to be in the "src" folder, not in the "assets"

Comment: I figured it out by disabling the web pack encore bundle in my full stack Symfony and just installing webix, worked as the docs implied. Thanks!